# #1327 - Undeclared variable: table_name

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1327

I was rolling some queries into a stored procedure and I hit the `#1327 - Undeclared variable` error ... the odd thing though is that **the variable it claims is undeclared is actually a table name**.

---

**Working through the problem**

So I extracted the bit of the procedure where it was falling over and tried to run it as a normal SQL query directly on the database through PHPMyAdmin... same thing. After much tinkering it seems to be where I'm joining another table.

If I run the query on a single table, it's fine, like this:

```
SET @i_channel_id = 3;
SET @i_product_id = 90;

SELECT 
`product_status_to_channel`.`status_code` INTO @s_status_code

FROM `product_status_to_channel`

WHERE `product_status_to_channel`.`channel_id` = @i_channel_id
AND `product_status_to_channel`.`product_id` = @i_product_id

ORDER BY IF(`product_status_to_channel`.`date` IS NULL, 1, 0) ASC, 
    `product_status_to_channel`.`date` DESC

LIMIT 0, 1;

SELECT @s_status_code AS status_code;
```

Which outputs *'LIVE'* as the `status_code` in PHPMyAdmin - which is fine.

---

However, when I try and `JOIN` to the message table to find the associated status message, I get the error: `#1327 - Undeclared variable: product_status_to_channel_lang` ... but `product_status_to_channel_lang` is a table?!

```
SET @i_channel_id = 3;
SET @i_language_id = 3;
SET @i_product_id = 90;

SELECT 
`product_status_to_channel`.`status_code` INTO @s_status_code,
`product_status_to_channel_lang`.`string` INTO @s_status_message

FROM `product_status_to_channel`

LEFT JOIN `product_status_to_channel_lang`
    ON `product_status_to_channel`.`product_status_to_channel_id` = `product_status_to_channel_lang`.`product_status_to_channel_id`
    AND `product_status_to_channel_lang`.`language_id` = @i_language_id

WHERE `product_status_to_channel`.`channel_id` = @i_channel_id
AND `product_status_to_channel`.`product_id` = @i_product_id

ORDER BY IF(`product_status_to_channel`.`date` IS NULL, 1, 0) ASC, `product_status_to_channel`.`date` DESC

LIMIT 0, 1;

SELECT @s_status_code AS status_code, @s_status_message AS status_message;
```

Is it trying to evaluate `product_status_to_channel_lang.product_status_to_channel_id` as a variable on the JOIN?

```
LEFT JOIN `product_status_to_channel_lang`
    ON `product_status_to_channel`.`product_status_to_channel_id` = `product_status_to_channel_lang`.`product_status_to_channel_id`
```

I assume I'm overlooking something obvious?

I've tried this on both:

- a Win7 box running xampp with MySQL 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- a Debian box running MySQL 5.1.73-1-log - (Debian)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind - it was something obvious:

```
SELECT 
`product_status_to_channel`.`status_code` INTO @s_status_code,
`product_status_to_channel_lang`.`string` INTO @s_status_message
```

Should be:

```
SELECT 
`product_status_to_channel`.`status_code`, 
`product_status_to_channel_lang`.`string` 

INTO 
@s_status_code, 
@s_status_message
```

... it must be Friday, it took literally a couple of hours to see that.

---

```
... INTO @s_status_code,
`product_status_to_channel_lang`.`string` ...
```

^That's where it's trying to assign `product_status_to_channel_lang` to being a variable into which to put data.